# Where exactly is value of NSTokenField applied when using Binding?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, appkit, nstextfield, nstokenfield

I'm currently using an `NSTokenField` with a binding of its value to an `NSArrayController` keypath configured in IB. This works all well.

Now I'm having difficulties adjusting the initial size of the NSTokenField to the initial data it's being populated with by the NSArrayController - I'm missing a hook to react to the value being set. [According to Apple's Binding Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CocoaBindings/Concepts/MessageFlow.html) explaining the inner workings of a binding with the example of an `NSTextField` (the base class for `NSTokenField`) it should be `setObjectValue:` that is invoked at some point to fill the `NSTokenField` with data. Most interestingly this method is never called. So to find my out where else the token field gets its data from the array controller, I tried the following:

```
- (void)setObjectValue:(id)objectValue {
    [super setObjectValue:objectValue];
    NSLog(@" setObjectValue with: %@", objectValue);
}
- (void)setValue:(id)value forKey:(NSString *)key {
    [super setValue:value forKey:key];
    NSLog(@" Set value %@ for key %@", value, key);
}

- (void)setValue:(id)value forKeyPath:(NSString *)keyPath {
    [super setValue:value forKeyPath:keyPath];
    NSLog(@" Set value %@ for keypath %@", value, keyPath);
}

- (void)setValuesForKeysWithDictionary:(NSDictionary<NSString *,id> *)keyedValues {
    [super setValuesForKeysWithDictionary:keyedValues];
    NSLog(@" Set value for keys with dict %@", keyedValues);
}

- (void)observeValueForKeyPath:(NSString *)keyPath
                      ofObject:(id)object
                        change:(NSDictionary<NSKeyValueChangeKey,id> *)change
                       context:(void *)context {
    [super observeValueForKeyPath:keyPath ofObject:object change:change context:context];
    NSLog(@" keyPath: %@ ofObject: %@ change: %@ context: %@", keyPath, object, change, context);
}
```

No one of these methods ever fires, at least not for any of the `value` key paths of the NSTokenField. So - how *is* the value of the token field set? At the moment to me it's pure magic and the situation leaves me clueless.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The value is set in `-[NSTokenFieldCell setObjectValue:]`. I don't know why it's the cell instead of the control.